# Why does layer 4 (the transport layer) of the Open System Interaction divide data into several packets?

Tags: network-protocols, osi

**From the book**

> Layer 4 - Transport: On networks data is divided into several packets.
>   When you are transferring a big file, this file is sliced into several
>   small packets, and then the computer at the other end gets these
>   packets and put the file back together.

Why is this done? Is it because of the speed the file is transfered?

Comment: From *what* book?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are numerous reasons to break the file into smaller packets:
1. Network congestion - a single stream of data from one device would prevent other devices from getting time on the network until the file was fully transferred.
2. Breaking the file into small packets allows for devices between the two endpoints (routers and switches) to reduce the amount of memory needed to handle a given packet.
3. If a single packet is corrupted or lost in flight, it can be resent without starting over.